# Kubuntu has two different User Management programs in "System Settings"

Tags: kubuntu, user-management

In System Settings, I am seeing two different programs for User Management.

[image]

One of them is pretty highly effective, it's the one on the left that says "User Management". A window pops up asking for my authentication and I get a fairly powerful tool for managing users:

[image]

If I click on "User Manager", however, I get this. Isn't this Unity's user manager??

[image]

It can't really do much and I don't know why it's even there. How can I get rid of it? (And which is supposed to be the default one? I assume it's the former.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**KDE / Kubuntu user managers**

KDE user tool: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kuser&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Old Kubuntu user tool: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=userconfig&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Current Kubuntu user tool: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=user-manager&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

You could install/remove the packages.

More of the Kubuntu user management can be found from the Kubuntu Forums thread: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?59417-User-Management